# In Markdown how does one keep multiple paragraphs within a single bullet point?

Tags: markdown

In a markdown file I'm rendering using Kramdown I have a list like this:

- First bullet point, paragraph 1

Paragraph 2

- New bullet point, paragraph 1

Paragraph 2

and so forth. The problem is how do I get the second, third, fourth and nth paragraph indented like the first paragraph is? This I want because I want it clear where the list indicated by bullet points, in fact, ends.

I have tried using `>>` and `::` before the new paragraphs underneath the same bullet point, but neither have produced the desired effect, namely with `>>` I get:

- First bullet point, paragraph 1

  > > Paragraph 2
- Second bullet point, paragraph 1

  > > Paragraph 2

Likewise with `::` I get:

- First bullet point, paragraph 1

:: Paragraph 2

- Second bullet point, paragraph 1

:: Paragraph 2

Likewise if I use `&nbsp;` (which adds a space) all it does is it indents the start of the paragraph, but not the rest of it. So, does anyone know a way to fix this dilemma?

I know a HTML solution—merely creating a HTML list, which caters better to new paragraphs under the one bullet point—but I'd like a markdown solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?  If so, add four spaces before each sub-paragraph. Also, review the [Markdown tutorial](https://commonmark.org/help/tutorial/10-nestedLists.html).

```
 - **item 1 para 1**:  this is para 1 narrative text  this is para 2 narrative text this is para 2 narrative text this is para 2 narrative text this is para 2 narrative text this is para 2 narrative text  
 
    _item 1 para 2_: this is para 2 narrative text this is para 2 narrative text this is para 2 narrative text this is para 2 narrative text  

    _item 1 para 2_: this is para 2 narrative text this is para 2 narrative text this is para 2 narrative text this is para 2 narrative text 

 - **item 2 para 1**: blah blah blah  
  
    _item 2 para 2_: this is para 2 narrative text this is para 2 narrative text this is para 2 narrative text this is para 2 narrative text
```

Answer (score 14):

[Indent the paragraph with four spaces](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#adding-elements-in-lists).

Comment: Sure doesn't work with StackOverflow's markdown! Turns it into a code block!